# Question about using a jQuery plugin over a series of matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery In Place Editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) to make allow in place editing of a few text elements in my page.

```
$(".entry_name").editInPlace({
    url: "/entries/change_name",
    params: "entry_id=XXX"
});
```

The `params` option allows me to send some parameters along with the post request. I need to specify a different `entry_id` for each element that matches the `.entry_name` selector. An example of a matched element is:

```
<span id="entry_name_24" class="entry_name" data-entry_id="24">example</span>
```

So in this example, the `params` option should be `entry_id=24`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `editInPlace` on each element separately:

```
$(".entry_name").each(function(){
    $(this).editInPlace({
        url: "/entries/change_name",
        params: "entry_id="+$(this).data('entry_id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick-

```
$(".entry_name").editInPlace({
    url: "/entries/change_name",
    params: "entry_id"+this.data('entry_id')
});
```

Comment: no it will not.. this will just run once at the time you invoke the method and just populate the params passed to the `editInPlace` call. Not a per element execution..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$(".entry_name").each(function(){
    var currentID = $(this).data('entry_id');

    $(this).editInPlace({
        url: "/entries/change_name",
        params: "entry_id=" + currentID 
    });
});
```

<strike>But keep in mind that the plugin (*according to the **Usage** section*) already passes the id of the element when submitting, but with another name `element_id`</strike>

> Once the in-place editor form is submitted, it sends a POST request to the URL that is specified in the editor’s parameters ***along with three form fields***:
>
> - **original_html**; the original text in the in-place editor container
> - **update_value**; the new value of the text from the in-place editor
> - **element_id**; the id attribute of the in-place editor

**edit :** sorry, missed that you are getting the `entry_id` and not the actual `id` (*although you could extract it from the actual `id`*)